# my Java code prints numbers instead of characters

Tags: java, char

I want to enter string value and writing first char to screen.

Code:

```
    Scanner giris = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.print("Enter Name: ");
    String ad = giris.next();
    System.out.print("Enter Second Name: ");
    String ikinciad = giris.next();
    System.out.print("Enter Lastname: ");
    String soyad = giris.next();
    
    char one = ad.charAt(0); //ilk karakterini almak için 0 yazdik
    char two = ikinciad.charAt(0); //ikinci olsaydi 1 yazardik 
    char three = soyad.charAt(0);
    
    System.out.print("Initials: ");
    System.out.print(one+two+three);
    
    giris.close();
```

Output:

```
     Enter Name: cem
     Enter Second Name: ahmet
     Enter Lastname: mehmet
     Initials: 305
```

Comment: `char` is a (specialized) unsigned number. If you want that to work, you need to 'signal' that a string is required: `System.out.print(""+one+two+three);`

Comment: `+` only works as string concatenation if at least one operand is a `String` - not the case in posted code - Java Language Specification: [15.18. Additive Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18): "*If the type of either operand of a `+` operator is `String`, then the operation is string concatenation.*"